# How can I add a Facebook "Like" button to my app with FBConnect

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app, I need to put a Like button that will make the user Like a specific link. The link is not a Facebook Post.

currently I'm using the FBConnect Library hosted here
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

That lib uses the new SDK with OAuth.

I have tried various things but none have worked so i have no useful code to post.

My objective is simple: "Like" a link.

How can I achieve that?

~Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a UIWebView and place the "Like" button code in an HTML document. Has worked fairly well for me.

This will also allow you to customize the UIWebView to have a clear background, no scrolling, etc. as well as CSS to match any color scheme your app may have.

Comment: Ultimately I have come to doing this.

However this forces me to login the user a second time (one for the api, second for webKit), do you know a work around this?

Comment: You can add the FBConnect api to your app. If the user is logged in through yur app, they shouldn't have to login through the web.

Answer (score 1):

Liking is not available via API, and as far as developer discussions on facebook said, it wont be available in near future. Sorry to tell you that.

But you can try to alter your idea, just post your URLs to the users profile.